# Is it possible to deobfuscate this string of Lua Code?

Tags: lua, obfuscation

I have a string of lua code that is obfuscated. I'm wondering if it's possible to deobfuscate it, or to figure out how it was obfuscated, as I've never encountered anything like it before.

```
-- hint: require=print
local lIl1li1IIlI111lIill1I = assert local lIl1liIi1i11lii1I1IiI = select local liiIIiilI11li1III1i = tonumber local I1liI1i1Il11lIi11l1 = unpack local llliilI1II1lillI111 = pcall local lIliiIiiIIIIIi111Illi = setfenv local i1IliliIil11IIili1l = setmetatable local lIl11I11iIiilIliIlIII = type local lilIi1I1iliiiI1I1Il = getfenv local lIlIlI1iI1illIiIll1i1 = tostring local lII1Iil11llII1II1Ii = error local lIlIli1lIii1IlIlIlIIl = string.sub local iii1Illi11lIil1iIl1 = string.byte local ll1li1l1IIIlIlllii1 = string.char local lIl111IIII11liiIl1II1 = string.rep local lIlI111l1iIllIII1Iiil = string.gsub local l1lIl1lll11l11l1IlI = string.match local i1Illl1Ili1il1I11lI = #{6133} local lIli1IiIii11iilil1i1i = {} local lIll1i1IiI11IiIlliIIi = 1 local function IIi1IIlI1IIIii1i1II(illIi11ilIIIllIi1II, lIl1lI1li1IIIl1111Ill) local lIliiillii1ilI11il1Il illIi11ilIIIllIi1II = lIlI111l1iIllIII1Iiil(lIlIli1lIii1IlIlIlIIl(illIi11ilIIIllIi1II, 5), "..", function(l1IIlIIlii1lillIii1) if iii1Illi11lIil1iIl1(l1IIlIIlii1lillIii1, 2) == 71 then lIliiillii1ilI11il1Il = liiIIiilI11li1III1i(lIlIli1lIii1IlIlIlIIl(l1IIlIIlii1lillIii1, 1, 1)) return "" else local I1Il11ll11iIiilIIi1 = ll1li1l1IIIlIlllii1(liiIIiilI11li1III1i(l1IIlIIlii1lillIii1, 16)) if lIliiillii1ilI11il1Il then local Il1ill1IliliIilllII = lIl111IIII11liiIl1II1(I1Il11ll11iIiilIIi1, lIliiillii1ilI11il1Il) lIliiillii1ilI11il1Il = nil return Il1ill1IliliIilllII else return I1Il11ll11iIiilIIi1 end end end) local function iI11l1ili1Ill1IiiIl() local l1lIiliIilI1i1lIl1i = iii1Illi11lIil1iIl1(illIi11ilIIIllIi1II, lIll1i1IiI11IiIlliIIi, lIll1i1IiI11IiIlliIIi) lIll1i1IiI11IiIlliIIi = lIll1i1IiI11IiIlliIIi + 1 return l1lIiliIilI1i1lIl1i end local function lIl1lllIlI1iil1IIiil1() local l1lIiliIilI1i1lIl1i, I1Il11ll11iIiilIIi1, Il1ill1IliliIilllII, lIliIiiIiiI1iIliIiI1I = iii1Illi11lIil1iIl1(illIi11ilIIIllIi1II, lIll1i1IiI11IiIlliIIi, lIll1i1IiI11IiIlliIIi + 3) lIll1i1IiI11IiIlliIIi = lIll1i1IiI11IiIlliIIi + 4 return lIliIiiIiiI1iIliIiI1I * 16777216 + Il1ill1IliliIilllII * 65536 + I1Il11ll11iIiilIIi1 * 256 + l1lIiliIilI1i1lIl1i end local function lIl1IlIIi1Iii1IIIIIli(i1lI11I11i1lIIll1l1, IiiIi1Iliii1lilil1i, lIlIlIl1I11iliiiIii) if lIlIlIl1I11iliiiIii then local llIiI1111iliIilIIIl, i1lili1lIi1il111l1l = 0, 0 for iiI1llli1I1IiiIlIIl = IiiIi1Iliii1lilil1i, lIlIlIl1I11iliiiIii do llIiI1111iliIilIIIl = llIiI1111iliIilIIIl + 2 ^ i1lili1lIi1il111l1l * lIl1IlIIi1Iii1IIIIIli(i1lI11I11i1lIIll1l1, iiI1llli1I1IiiIlIIl) i1lili1lIi1il111l1l = i1lili1lIi1il111l1l + 1 end return llIiI1111iliIilIIIl else local iIil11llllIlII1iiII = 2 ^ (IiiIi1Iliii1lilil1i - 1) return iIil11llllIlII1iiII <= i1lI11I11i1lIIll1l1 % (iIil11llllIlII1iiII + iIil11llllIlII1iiII) and 1 or 0 end end local function i11l1l11llll1iiIl1i() local l1lIiliIilI1i1lIl1i, I1Il11ll11iIiilIIi1 = lIl1lllIlI1iil1IIiil1(), lIl1lllIlI1iil1IIiil1() if l1lIiliIilI1i1lIl1i == 0 and I1Il11ll11iIiilIIi1 == 0 then return 0 end return (-2 * lIl1IlIIi1Iii1IIIIIli(I1Il11ll11iIiilIIi1, 32) + 1) * 2 ^ (lIl1IlIIi1Iii1IIIIIli(I1Il11ll11iIiilIIi1, 21, 31) - 1023) * ((lIl1IlIIi1Iii1IIIIIli(I1Il11ll11iIiilIIi1, 1, 20) * 4294967296 + l1lIiliIilI1i1lIl1i) / 4503599627370496 + 1) end local function IIII1l1II11Ilil11i1(i1lI11iIi11li1li11I) local i1Il11l1I1iI1i1iIi1 = { iii1Illi11lIil1iIl1(illIi11ilIIIllIi1II, lIll1i1IiI11IiIlliIIi, lIll1i1IiI11IiIlliIIi + 3) } lIll1i1IiI11IiIlliIIi = lIll1i1IiI11IiIlliIIi + 4 local lIliiil1l1i1il111ii1i = { nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil } for iiI1llli1I1IiiIlIIl = 1, 8 do lIliiil1l1i1il111ii1i[iiI1llli1I1IiiIlIIl] = lIl1IlIIi1Iii1IIIIIli(i1lI11iIi11li1li11I, iiI1llli1I1IiiIlIIl) end local lIlIiIllii1IIi1II1ii1 = "" for iiI1llli1I1IiiIlIIl = 1, 4 do local llIiI1111iliIilIIIl, i1lili1lIi1il111l1l = 0, 0 for lll1iil1iliIIIIlllI = 1, 8 do local iil1l1llil1lII1IIiI = lIl1IlIIi1Iii1IIIIIli(i1Il11l1I1iI1i1iIi1[iiI1llli1I1IiiIlIIl], lll1iil1iliIIIIlllI) if lIliiil1l1i1il111ii1i[lll1iil1iliIIIIlllI] == 1 then iil1l1llil1lII1IIiI = iil1l1llil1lII1IIiI == 1 and 0 or 1 end llIiI1111iliIilIIIl = llIiI1111iliIilIIIl + 2 ^ i1lili1lIi1il111l1l * iil1l1llil1lII1IIiI i1lili1lIi1il111l1l = i1lili1lIi1il111l1l + 1 end lIlIiIllii1IIi1II1ii1 = lIlIiIllii1IIi1II1ii1 .. lIlIiIllii1IIi1II1ii1.char(llIiI1111iliIilIIIl) end local l1lIiliIilI1i1lIl1i, I1Il11ll11iIiilIIi1, Il1ill1IliliIilllII, lIliIiiIiiI1iIliIiI1I = iii1Illi11lIil1iIl1(lIlIiIllii1IIi1II1ii1, 1, 4) return lIliIiiIiiI1iIliIiI1I * 16777216 + Il1ill1IliliIilllII * 65536 + I1Il11ll11iIiilIIi1 * 256 + l1lIiliIilI1i1lIl1i end local function lIlIIIlIlliIl1IlIllI1(i1lI11iIi11li1li11I) local I1l1ll1llilil11i1iI = lIl1lllIlI1iil1IIiil1() lIll1i1IiI11IiIlliIIi = lIll1i1IiI11IiIlliIIi + I1l1ll1llilil11i1iI local lIliiil1l1i1il111ii1i = { nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil } for iiI1llli1I1IiiIlIIl = 1, 8 do lIliiil1l1i1il111ii1i[iiI1llli1I1IiiIlIIl] = lIl1IlIIi1Iii1IIIIIli(i1lI11iIi11li1li11I, iiI1llli1I1IiiIlIIl) end local lIlIiIllii1IIi1II1ii1 = "" for iiI1llli1I1IiiIlIIl = 1, I1l1ll1llilil11i1iI do local llIiI1111iliIilIIIl, i1lili1lIi1il111l1l = 0, 0 for lll1iil1iliIIIIlllI = 1, 8 do local iil1l1llil1lII1IIiI = lIl1IlIIi1Iii1IIIIIli(iii1Illi11lIil1iIl1(illIi11ilIIIllIi1II, lIll1i1IiI11IiIlliIIi - I1l1ll1llilil11i1iI + iiI1llli1I1IiiIlIIl - 1), lll1iil1iliIIIIlllI) if lIliiil1l1i1il111ii1i[lll1iil1iliIIIIlllI] == 1 then iil1l1llil1lII1IIiI = iil1l1llil1lII1IIiI == 1 and 0 or 1 end llIiI1111iliIilIIIl = llIiI1111iliIilIIIl + 2 ^ i1lili1lIi1il111l1l * iil1l1llil1lII1IIiI i1lili1lIi1il111l1l = i1lili1lIi1il111l1l + 1 end lIlIiIllii1IIi1II1ii1 = lIlIiIllii1IIi1II1ii1 .. lIlIiIllii1IIi1II1ii1.char(llIiI1111iliIilIIIl) end return lIlIiIllii1IIi1II1ii1 end local I1iIliII11IIiI11lII = iI11l1ili1Ill1IiiIl() local IlII1IiiIlI1ilIIli1 = iI11l1ili1Ill1IiiIl() local function lIlIlI1Ii1li1lI1lIIli() local lII1IlI1IiIl1IliIl1 = { [125970] = {}, [96100] = {}, [6375] = {}, [71002] = {} } local iII1i1llIliIl11Ili1 = lIl1lllIlI1iil1IIiil1() for iiI1llli1I1IiiIlIIl = i1Illl1Ili1il1I11lI, iII1i1llIliIl11Ili1 do lII1IlI1IiIl1IliIl1[6375][iiI1llli1I1IiiIlIIl - i1Illl1Ili1il1I11lI] = lIlIlI1Ii1li1lI1lIIli() end lIl1lllIlI1iil1IIiil1() iI11l1ili1Ill1IiiIl() lIl1lllIlI1iil1IIiil1() local iII1i1llIliIl11Ili1 = lIl1lllIlI1iil1IIiil1() - (#{ 3676, 3338, 1561, 6447, 963, 2963, 753, 3759, 1372, 2014, 4435, 3772, 6814, 6363, 2988, 5918, 6818, 403, 4656, 2024, 2587, 6179 } + 133708) for iiI1llli1I1IiiIlIIl = i1Illl1Ili1il1I11lI, iII1i1llIliIl11Ili1 do local Iii111iI1ililI1lill = {} local lIl11I11iIiilIliIlIII = iI11l1ili1Ill1IiiIl() if lIl11I11iIiilIliIlIII == #{ 6889, 5877, 4793, 1853, 2940, 4188, 1170, 250, 4278, 1947, 2733, 3303, 6890, 6099, 3903, 3124, 788, 1268, 1055, 6484 } + 144 then Iii111iI1ililI1lill[73920] = i11l1l11llll1iiIl1i() end if lIl11I11iIiilIliIlIII == #{ 4509, 4622, 4716, 6937, 1872, 2514, 2674, 5406, 1358, 2914, 5029, 3201, 6764, 6548, 5815, 4318, 845, 277, 1011, 755, 386, 3871, 6906 } + 202 then Iii111iI1ililI1lill[73920] = iI11l1ili1Ill1IiiIl() + lIl1lllIlI1iil1IIiil1() + i11l1l11llll1iiIl1i() end if lIl11I11iIiilIliIlIII == #{ 6554, 4258, 6809, 1034, 4699, 6129, 144, 562, 3722, 6109, 1499, 3228, 5115, 1983, 1422, 5640, 599, 1609, 1341, 4034, 1041, 5095, 1810 } + 158 then Iii111iI1ililI1lill[73920] = lIlIIIlIlliIl1IlIllI1(I1iIliII11IIiI11lII) end if lIl11I11iIiilIliIlIII == #{ 6911, 5320, 3158, 6486, 2959, 232, 3903, 4060, 6495, 4144, 224, 5026, 1661, 4890, 1294, 2921, 2833, 5965, 4623, 5319, 5328 } + 34 then Iii111iI1ililI1lill[73920] = i11l1l11llll1iiIl1i() end if lIl11I11iIiilIliIlIII == #{ 4936, 6580, 293, 1684, 5023, 6398, 3856, 6374, 1432, 669, 5156, 1805, 1370, 231, 1248, 102, 1031, 4061, 1919, 1499 } + 232 then Iii111iI1ililI1lill[73920] = #{ 2936, 6037, 5659, 3860, 4411, 3179, 1472, 6946, 3242, 4882, 2001, 239, 629, 5018, 6811, 4869, 1335, 3902, 137, 3018, 3251, 1291, 2040, 3697 } + 51351 == #{ 2156, 4124, 6111, 2227, 195, 2202, 1658, 6202, 6782, 2765, 540, 6811, 5036, 10, 5979, 3012, 5354, 711, 5395, 1771, 2035, 5016, 5719 } + 64657 end if lIl11I11iIiilIliIlIII == #{ 4512, 1698, 3147, 4426, 1912, 2262, 4838, 6515, 2203, 4696, 2965, 5088, 4527, 966, 5043, 5352, 3683, 2089, 6786, 3514, 3080 } + 105 then Iii111iI1ililI1lill[73920] = #{ 5777, 1747, 5068, 5592, 2350, 6408, 5599, 2672, 3148, 4132, 1530, 6784, 2931, 5212, 990, 4650, 5049, 4840, 1212, 4258, 2523, 6150 } + 7078 == #{ 5777, 1747, 5068, 5592, 2350, 6408, 5599, 2672, 3148, 4132, 1530, 6784, 2931, 5212, 990, 4650, 5049, 4840, 1212, 4258, 2523, 6150 } + 7078 end if lIl11I11iIiilIliIlIII == #{ 88, 2594, 2638, 2331, 5723, 4111, 4322, 4793, 3166, 3608, 4391, 4726, 18, 4042, 3429, 6577, 339, 3310, 3135, 3204, 5506, 3376, 3109, 1124 } + 109 then Iii111iI1ililI1lill[73920] = iI11l1ili1Ill1IiiIl() end if lIl11I11iIiilIliIlIII == #{ 4854, 4314, 1450, 3196, 1192, 59, 6163, 3624, 6318, 5199, 6407, 5548, 3313, 3437, 1700, 1117, 4065, 2726, 2462, 1720, 4265, 5528 } + 101 then Iii111iI1ililI1lill[73920] = iI11l1ili1Ill1IiiIl() + lIl1lllIlI1iil1IIiil1() + i11l1l11llll1iiIl1i() end if lIl11I11iIiilIliIlIII == #{ 1572, 2448, 6961, 1640, 3821, 1140, 6529, 2473, 901, 4829, 3958, 6376, 1307, 1447, 229, 6684, 3711, 4706, 5535, 872, 5719, 6032, 6189 } + 21 then Iii111iI1ililI1lill[73920] = lIlIIIlIlliIl1IlIllI1(I1iIliII11IIiI11lII) end lII1IlI1IiIl1IliIl1[71002][iiI1llli1I1IiiIlIIl - i1Illl1Ili1il1I11lI] = Iii111iI1ililI1lill end local iII1i1llIliIl11Ili1 = lIl1lllIlI1iil1IIiil1() for iiI1llli1I1IiiIlIIl = i1Illl1Ili1il1I11lI, iII1i1llIliIl11Ili1 do lII1IlI1IiIl1IliIl1[125970][iiI1llli1I1IiiIlIIl] = lIl1lllIlI1iil1IIiil1() end local iII1i1llIliIl11Ili1 = lIl1lllIlI1iil1IIiil1() - (#{ 3836, 3451, 4278, 5224, 1622, 6398, 5682, 4648, 448, 366, 4573, 4734, 4354, 4947, 5951, 6838, 6672, 2726, 2235, 1729, 4693 } + 133686) for iiI1llli1I1IiiIlIIl = i1Illl1Ili1il1I11lI, iII1i1llIliIl11Ili1 do local lIlIil1ll111lii11Iill = {} local lIlI1llililili11Iii1i = IIII1l1II11Ilil11i1(IlII1IiiIlI1ilIIli1) lIlIil1ll111lii11Iill[77834] = lIl1IlIIi1Iii1IIIIIli(lIlI1llililili11Iii1i, #{ 2954, 2723, 3265, 4788, 6811, 5670, 3565, 4706, 2262, 3907, 1670, 6737, 3811, 538, 3186, 1776, 1965, 543, 3484, 5758, 4626, 5316, 4401 } + 4, #{ 892, 2231, 3441, 3852, 6703, 5999, 3887, 6233, 1324, 86, 3853, 3277, 5651, 3346, 5746, 3953, 4077, 5774, 6583, 5872, 3189, 1853, 4290 } + 9) lIlIil1ll111lii11Iill[25269] = lIl1IlIIi1Iii1IIIIIli(lIlI1llililili11Iii1i, #{ 1682, 2389, 3352, 6090, 4852, 4990, 3980, 1168, 3679, 4064 }, #{ 3701, 3903, 3855, 3336, 5137, 6167, 6238, 6678, 4385, 6097, 6876, 5315, 81, 0, 4773, 480, 4329, 1675 }) lIlIil1ll111lii11Iill[127128] = lIl1IlIIi1Iii1IIIIIli(lIlI1llililili11Iii1i, #{6729}, #{ 4785, 6112, 3590, 5779, 989, 5095, 6070, 3287, 2159 }) lIlIil1ll111lii11Iill[43240] = lIl1IlIIi1Iii1IIIIIli(lIlI1llililili11Iii1i, #{6552}, #{ 992, 438, 3490, 2052, 246, 4278, 6478, 520, 1623, 5031, 861, 1363, 3861, 5598, 2033, 4484, 6271, 920 }) lIlIil1ll111lii11Iill[23653] = lIl1IlIIi1Iii1IIIIIli(lIlI1llililili11Iii1i, #{ 6553, 6335, 4396, 1359, 4305, 4071, 970, 6213, 3658, 64, 612, 4345, 4062, 1615, 5402, 1651, 1943, 2982, 3973 }, #{ 80, 6226, 4232, 2532, 2200, 3003, 3419, 2185, 4715, 1388, 2992, 4330, 4413, 772, 3748, 4719, 5309, 3137, 6222, 61, 4205, 6754, 1982, 2147 } + 2) lII1IlI1IiIl1IliIl1[96100][iiI1llli1I1IiiIlIIl] = lIlIil1ll111lii11Iill end lII1IlI1IiIl1IliIl1[126833] = iI11l1ili1Ill1IiiIl() iI11l1ili1Ill1IiiIl() lII1IlI1IiIl1IliIl1[110011] = iI11l1ili1Ill1IiiIl() lII1IlI1IiIl1IliIl1[43118] = iI11l1ili1Ill1IiiIl() lIl1lllIlI1iil1IIiil1() iI11l1ili1Ill1IiiIl() return lII1IlI1IiIl1IliIl1 end local function lIliIiIl1ili1IillIiIl(lII1IlI1IiIl1IliIl1, lIl1lI1li1IIIl1111Ill, lIiii1IiIil1I1iiiiI) local lI111i1ilIl111ii111, lIl1l11l1IiI1l1IilIii = -1, -1 local lIliliiIi1lIIIIl1111i = lII1IlI1IiIl1IliIl1[96100] local i11lliiiilIliiiIl11 = i1IliliIil11IIili1l({}, { __index = function(lIllll1ill1I1Iili11l1, Il11IiIIi11iIli1l1l) local lIlIiIllii1IIi1II1ii1 = lII1IlI1IiIl1IliIl1[71002][Il11IiIIi11iIli1l1l] if lIlIli1lIii1IlIlIlIIl(lIl11I11iIiilIliIlIII(lIlIiIllii1IIi1II1ii1[73920]), 1, 1) == "s" then return { [73920] = lIlIli1lIii1IlIlIlIIl(lIlIiIllii1IIi1II1ii1[73920], 6) } end return lIlIiIllii1IIi1II1ii1 end }) local li1iI1Iiilll1i11lIl = 126833 local lIliiIIiiIilil1liilii = lII1IlI1IiIl1IliIl1[6375] local IiIIillI1ll1IllIiIl = 73920 local lIliiIlIi1ll1IIIlII1I = lII1IlI1IiIl1IliIl1[110011] local IlIlI11lIi1I1il11II = 77834 local i1l11I1lI11l11ilIi1 = lII1IlI1IiIl1IliIl1[125970] local IllIi1i11l11ilIIIiI = 127128 local function lIlIIIiIIi1lIiIlII111(...) local l1lIliii11iIi1I1l11 = 0 local IlliIiilIli11liIlIl = { I1liI1i1Il11lIi11l1({}, 1, lII1IlI1IiIl1IliIl1[43118]) } local I11I11llIIiI1lI1i1I = 1 local i1I11il1iIi1lIil1I1 = {} local liII1l1IlliiIl11ii1 = {} local iIl1i11IIiIlIi1ilI1 = 1 local lIl1lI1li1IIIl1111Ill = lilIi1I1iliiiI1I1Il() local lIllI11Iii11iIIllii1i = { ... } local illII1II1iIIIilliil = #lIllI11Iii11iIIllii1i - 1 for iiI1llli1I1IiiIlIIl = 0, illII1II1iIIIilliil do if iiI1llli1I1IiiIlIIl < lIliiIlIi1ll1IIIlII1I then IlliIiilIli11liIlIl[iiI1llli1I1IiiIlIIl] = lIllI11Iii11iIIllii1i[iiI1llli1I1IiiIlIIl + 1] end end local function lIlliiIiilliiIll1li1i(...) local Il1ill1IliliIilllII = lIl1liIi1i11lii1I1IiI("#", ...) local lIllll1ill1I1Iili11l1 = { ... } return Il1ill1IliliIilllII, lIllll1ill1I1Iili11l1 end local ill1liill1illiliill = #{ 6729, 3559, 1693, 4464, 6867, 4771, 3599, 4905, 4402, 2339, 3087, 4395, 4405, 4401, 4942, 4149, 4415, 6535, 3732, 2414, 1801, 1003, 3061, 6007 } + 131047 local lIlI1iiIIill1lillIIli local I111li1IIII1llIiiIl = { function(l11i111lI1ilIlilil1, lIli1iIllI1I1IlIIllll, lIl1lil1iI1llIIlIlIii, i1ilii11I1il1Iliil1) local lIlIlI1iiiliIIiil1i1l = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[127128] local iliIili1lIiIIIl1ilI = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[25269] local II11iiI1iI1i1lI1i1l = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[43240] - ill1liill1illiliill local l111I1iI1I1lilIIli1 = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[23653] local lIll1iiiIiIIliIIl1liI = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[43240] IlliIiilIli11liIlIl[l111I1iI1I1lilIIli1] = i11lliiiilIliiiIl11[lIll1iiiIiIIliIIl1liI][IiIIillI1ll1IllIiIl] end, function(l11i111lI1ilIlilil1) local l111I1iI1I1lilIIli1 = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[23653] local iliIili1lIiIIIl1ilI = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[25269] local lIll1iiiIiIIliIIl1liI = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[43240] local II11iiI1iI1i1lI1i1l = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[43240] - ill1liill1illiliill local lIlIlI1iiiliIIiil1i1l = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[127128] local iIIIliIlii1II111lIl = lIliiIIiiIilil1liilii[lIll1iiiIiIIliIIl1liI] local lIliiii1ilII1IlIlil1l = {} if iIIIliIlii1II111lIl[li1iI1Iiilll1i11lIl] > 0 then do local ii1II1l11iIli1i1ii1 = {} lIliiii1ilII1IlIlil1l = i1IliliIil11IIili1l({}, { __index = function(lIllll1ill1I1Iili11l1, Il11IiIIi11iIli1l1l) local iii1IlilI1lII1i1l1i = ii1II1l11iIli1i1ii1[Il11IiIIi11iIli1l1l] return iii1IlilI1lII1i1l1i[1][iii1IlilI1lII1i1l1i[2]] end, __newindex = function(lIllll1ill1I1Iili11l1, Il11IiIIi11iIli1l1l, IIlIll1lI11iI111lil) local iii1IlilI1lII1i1l1i = ii1II1l11iIli1i1ii1[Il11IiIIi11iIli1l1l] iii1IlilI1lII1i1l1i[1][iii1IlilI1lII1i1l1i[2]] = IIlIll1lI11iI111lil end }) for iiI1llli1I1IiiIlIIl = 1, iIIIliIlii1II111lIl[li1iI1Iiilll1i11lIl] do local Il1iIIilll1lillllii = lIliliiIi1lIIIIl1111i[I11I11llIIiI1lI1i1I] if Il1iIIilll1lillllii[IlIlI11lIi1I1il11II] == lI111i1ilIl111ii111 then ii1II1l11iIli1i1ii1[iiI1llli1I1IiiIlIIl - 1] = { IlliIiilIli11liIlIl, Il1iIIilll1lillllii[IllIi1i11l11ilIIIiI] } elseif Il1iIIilll1lillllii[IlIlI11lIi1I1il11II] == lIl1l11l1IiI1l1IilIii then ii1II1l11iIli1i1ii1[iiI1llli1I1IiiIlIIl - 1] = { lIiii1IiIil1I1iiiiI, Il1iIIilll1lillllii[IllIi1i11l11ilIIIiI] } end I11I11llIIiI1lI1i1I = I11I11llIIiI1lI1i1I + 1 end i1I11il1iIi1lIil1I1[#i1I11il1iIi1lIil1I1 + 1] = ii1II1l11iIli1i1ii1 end end local iIi11i1I1l1ii11iI11 = lIliIiIl1ili1IillIiIl(iIIIliIlii1II111lIl, lIl1lI1li1IIIl1111Ill, lIliiii1ilII1IlIlil1l) IlliIiilIli11liIlIl[l111I1iI1I1lilIIli1] = iIi11i1I1l1ii11iI11 end, nil, function(l11i111lI1ilIlilil1) local iliIili1lIiIIIl1ilI = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[25269] local II11iiI1iI1i1lI1i1l = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[43240] - ill1liill1illiliill local l111I1iI1I1lilIIli1 = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[23653] local lIlIlI1iiiliIIiil1i1l = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[127128] local lIll1iiiIiIIliIIl1liI = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[43240] if iliIili1lIiIIIl1ilI == 184 then return lIlI1iiIIill1lillIIli[8]({ [23653] = (l111I1iI1I1lilIIli1 - 81) % 256, [127128] = (lIlIlI1iiiliIIiil1i1l - 81) % 256, [43240] = 0 }) end lIiii1IiIil1I1iiiiI[lIlIlI1iiiliIIiil1i1l] = IlliIiilIli11liIlIl[l111I1iI1I1lilIIli1] end, nil, function(l11i111lI1ilIlilil1, lIli1iIllI1I1IlIIllll, lIl1lil1iI1llIIlIlIii, i1ilii11I1il1Iliil1) local II11iiI1iI1i1lI1i1l = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[43240] - ill1liill1illiliill local lIlIlI1iiiliIIiil1i1l = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[127128] local iliIili1lIiIIIl1ilI = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[25269] local l111I1iI1I1lilIIli1 = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[23653] local lIll1iiiIiIIliIIl1liI = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[43240] local i1lI11iIi11li1li11I if lIll1iiiIiIIliIIl1liI == 100000 then i1lI11iIi11li1li11I = IlliIiilIli11liIlIl[251] else i1lI11iIi11li1li11I = i11lliiiilIliiiIl11[lIll1iiiIiIIliIIl1liI][IiIIillI1ll1IllIiIl] end IlliIiilIli11liIlIl[l111I1iI1I1lilIIli1] = lIl1lI1li1IIIl1111Ill[i1lI11iIi11li1li11I] end, function(l11i111lI1ilIlilil1, lIli1iIllI1I1IlIIllll, lIl1lil1iI1llIIlIlIii) local II11iiI1iI1i1lI1i1l = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[43240] - ill1liill1illiliill local lIll1iiiIiIIliIIl1liI = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[43240] local iliIili1lIiIIIl1ilI = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[25269] local l111I1iI1I1lilIIli1 = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[23653] local lIlIlI1iiiliIIiil1i1l = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[127128] if iliIili1lIiIIIl1ilI == 127 then return lIlI1iiIIill1lillIIli[6]({ [23653] = (l111I1iI1I1lilIIli1 - 21) % 256, [127128] = (lIlIlI1iiiliIIiil1i1l - 21) % 256, [43240] = 0 }) end IlliIiilIli11liIlIl[l111I1iI1I1lilIIli1] = not IlliIiilIli11liIlIl[lIlIlI1iiiliIIiil1i1l] end, function(l11i111lI1ilIlilil1, lIli1iIllI1I1IlIIllll) local l111I1iI1I1lilIIli1 = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[23653] local lIlIlI1iiiliIIiil1i1l = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[127128] local iliIili1lIiIIIl1ilI = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[25269] local lIll1iiiIiIIliIIl1liI = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[43240] local II11iiI1iI1i1lI1i1l = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[43240] - ill1liill1illiliill IlliIiilIli11liIlIl[l111I1iI1I1lilIIli1] = lIlIlI1iiiliIIiil1i1l ~= 0 if iliIili1lIiIIIl1ilI ~= 0 then I11I11llIIiI1lI1i1I = I11I11llIIiI1lI1i1I + 1 end end, nil, function(l11i111lI1ilIlilil1, lIli1iIllI1I1IlIIllll) local II11iiI1iI1i1lI1i1l = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[43240] - ill1liill1illiliill local iliIili1lIiIIIl1ilI = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[25269] local lIlIlI1iiiliIIiil1i1l = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[127128] local lIll1iiiIiIIliIIl1liI = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[43240] local l111I1iI1I1lilIIli1 = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[23653] local lIi1i1iIll11lliiI1I = l111I1iI1I1lilIIli1 + 2 local IlllIl111lllliiIl1i = { IlliIiilIli11liIlIl[l111I1iI1I1lilIIli1](IlliIiilIli11liIlIl[l111I1iI1I1lilIIli1 + 1], IlliIiilIli11liIlIl[l111I1iI1I1lilIIli1 + 2]) } for iiI1llli1I1IiiIlIIl = 1, iliIili1lIiIIIl1ilI do IlliIiilIli11liIlIl[lIi1i1iIll11lliiI1I + iiI1llli1I1IiiIlIIl] = IlllIl111lllliiIl1i[iiI1llli1I1IiiIlIIl] end if IlliIiilIli11liIlIl[l111I1iI1I1lilIIli1 + 3] ~= nil then IlliIiilIli11liIlIl[l111I1iI1I1lilIIli1 + 2] = IlliIiilIli11liIlIl[l111I1iI1I1lilIIli1 + 3] else I11I11llIIiI1lI1i1I = I11I11llIIiI1lI1i1I + 1 end end, function(l11i111lI1ilIlilil1, lIli1iIllI1I1IlIIllll, lIl1lil1iI1llIIlIlIii, i1ilii11I1il1Iliil1) local l111I1iI1I1lilIIli1 = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[23653] local II11iiI1iI1i1lI1i1l = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[43240] - ill1liill1illiliill local iliIili1lIiIIIl1ilI = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[25269] local lIlIlI1iiiliIIiil1i1l = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[127128] local lIll1iiiIiIIliIIl1liI = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[43240] local i1lI11iIi11li1li11I if lIll1iiiIiIIliIIl1liI == 100000 then i1lI11iIi11li1li11I = IlliIiilIli11liIlIl[251] else i1lI11iIi11li1li11I = i11lliiiilIliiiIl11[lIll1iiiIiIIliIIl1liI][IiIIillI1ll1IllIiIl] end lIl1lI1li1IIIl1111Ill[i1lI11iIi11li1li11I] = IlliIiilIli11liIlIl[l111I1iI1I1lilIIli1] end, nil, function(l11i111lI1ilIlilil1) local lIll1iiiIiIIliIIl1liI = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[43240] local II11iiI1iI1i1lI1i1l = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[43240] - ill1liill1illiliill local iliIili1lIiIIIl1ilI = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[25269] local lIlIlI1iiiliIIiil1i1l = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[127128] local l111I1iI1I1lilIIli1 = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[23653] local iII1iIiii1i1iiiliii, IliIiil1i1IIilll1l1, II11IIiiiliili1llll if lIlIlI1iiiliIIiil1i1l ~= 1 then if lIlIlI1iiiliIIiil1i1l ~= 0 then IliIiil1i1IIilll1l1 = l111I1iI1I1lilIIli1 + lIlIlI1iiiliIIiil1i1l - 1 else IliIiil1i1IIilll1l1 = l1lIliii11iIi1I1l11 end IliIiil1i1IIilll1l1, iII1iIiii1i1iiiliii = lIlliiIiilliiIll1li1i(IlliIiilIli11liIlIl[l111I1iI1I1lilIIli1](I1liI1i1Il11lIi11l1(IlliIiilIli11liIlIl, l111I1iI1I1lilIIli1 + 1, IliIiil1i1IIilll1l1))) else IliIiil1i1IIilll1l1, iII1iIiii1i1iiiliii = lIlliiIiilliiIll1li1i(IlliIiilIli11liIlIl[l111I1iI1I1lilIIli1]()) end if iliIili1lIiIIIl1ilI ~= 1 then if iliIili1lIiIIIl1ilI ~= 0 then IliIiil1i1IIilll1l1 = l111I1iI1I1lilIIli1 + iliIili1lIiIIIl1ilI - 2 else IliIiil1i1IIilll1l1 = IliIiil1i1IIilll1l1 + l111I1iI1I1lilIIli1 end II11IIiiiliili1llll = 0 for iiI1llli1I1IiiIlIIl = l111I1iI1I1lilIIli1, IliIiil1i1IIilll1l1 do II11IIiiiliili1llll = II11IIiiiliili1llll + 1 IlliIiilIli11liIlIl[iiI1llli1I1IiiIlIIl] = iII1iIiii1i1iiiliii[II11IIiiiliili1llll] end end l1lIliii11iIi1I1l11 = IliIiil1i1IIilll1l1 - 1 end, nil, nil, function(l11i111lI1ilIlilil1, lIli1iIllI1I1IlIIllll, lIl1lil1iI1llIIlIlIii, i1ilii11I1il1Iliil1) local iliIili1lIiIIIl1ilI = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[25269] local l111I1iI1I1lilIIli1 = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[23653] local II11iiI1iI1i1lI1i1l = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[43240] - ill1liill1illiliill local lIll1iiiIiIIliIIl1liI = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[43240] local lIlIlI1iiiliIIiil1i1l = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[127128] IlliIiilIli11liIlIl[l111I1iI1I1lilIIli1] = { I1liI1i1Il11lIi11l1(lIli1IiIii11iilil1i1i, 1, lIlIlI1iiiliIIiil1i1l == 0 and 895 or lIlIlI1iiiliIIiil1i1l) } end } I111li1IIII1llIiiIl[3] = function(l11i111lI1ilIlilil1) local lIll1iiiIiIIliIIl1liI = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[43240] local l111I1iI1I1lilIIli1 = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[23653] local iliIili1lIiIIIl1ilI = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[25269] local lIlIlI1iiiliIIiil1i1l = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[127128] local II11iiI1iI1i1lI1i1l = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[43240] - ill1liill1illiliill if not not IlliIiilIli11liIlIl[lIlIlI1iiiliIIiil1i1l] == (iliIili1lIiIIIl1ilI == 0) then I11I11llIIiI1lI1i1I = I11I11llIIiI1lI1i1I + 1 else IlliIiilIli11liIlIl[l111I1iI1I1lilIIli1] = IlliIiilIli11liIlIl[lIlIlI1iiiliIIiil1i1l] end end I111li1IIII1llIiiIl[15] = function(l11i111lI1ilIlilil1, lIli1iIllI1I1IlIIllll) local l111I1iI1I1lilIIli1 = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[23653] local lIll1iiiIiIIliIIl1liI = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[43240] local lIlIlI1iiiliIIiil1i1l = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[127128] local II11iiI1iI1i1lI1i1l = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[43240] - ill1liill1illiliill local iliIili1lIiIIIl1ilI = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[25269] lIlIlI1iiiliIIiil1i1l = IlliIiilIli11liIlIl[lIlIlI1iiiliIIiil1i1l] if iliIili1lIiIIIl1ilI > 255 then iliIili1lIiIIIl1ilI = i11lliiiilIliiiIl11[iliIili1lIiIIIl1ilI - 256][IiIIillI1ll1IllIiIl] else iliIili1lIiIIIl1ilI = IlliIiilIli11liIlIl[iliIili1lIiIIIl1ilI] end IlliIiilIli11liIlIl[l111I1iI1I1lilIIli1 + 1] = lIlIlI1iiiliIIiil1i1l IlliIiilIli11liIlIl[l111I1iI1I1lilIIli1] = lIlIlI1iiiliIIiil1i1l[iliIili1lIiIIIl1ilI] end I111li1IIII1llIiiIl[5] = function(l11i111lI1ilIlilil1, lIli1iIllI1I1IlIIllll, lIl1lil1iI1llIIlIlIii) local lIll1iiiIiIIliIIl1liI = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[43240] local l111I1iI1I1lilIIli1 = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[23653] local lIlIlI1iiiliIIiil1i1l = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[127128] local II11iiI1iI1i1lI1i1l = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[43240] - ill1liill1illiliill local iliIili1lIiIIIl1ilI = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[25269] I11I11llIIiI1lI1i1I = I11I11llIIiI1lI1i1I + II11iiI1iI1i1lI1i1l end I111li1IIII1llIiiIl[0] = function(l11i111lI1ilIlilil1, lIli1iIllI1I1IlIIllll) local lIlIlI1iiiliIIiil1i1l = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[127128] local l111I1iI1I1lilIIli1 = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[23653] local II11iiI1iI1i1lI1i1l = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[43240] - ill1liill1illiliill local iliIili1lIiIIIl1ilI = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[25269] local lIll1iiiIiIIliIIl1liI = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[43240] if lIlIlI1iiiliIIiil1i1l > 255 then lIlIlI1iiiliIIiil1i1l = i11lliiiilIliiiIl11[lIlIlI1iiiliIIiil1i1l - 256][IiIIillI1ll1IllIiIl] else lIlIlI1iiiliIIiil1i1l = IlliIiilIli11liIlIl[lIlIlI1iiiliIIiil1i1l] end if iliIili1lIiIIIl1ilI > 255 then iliIili1lIiIIIl1ilI = i11lliiiilIliiiIl11[iliIili1lIiIIIl1ilI - 256][IiIIillI1ll1IllIiIl] else iliIili1lIiIIIl1ilI = IlliIiilIli11liIlIl[iliIili1lIiIIIl1ilI] end IlliIiilIli11liIlIl[l111I1iI1I1lilIIli1][lIlIlI1iiiliIIiil1i1l] = iliIili1lIiIIIl1ilI end I111li1IIII1llIiiIl[14] = function(l11i111lI1ilIlilil1, lIli1iIllI1I1IlIIllll, lIl1lil1iI1llIIlIlIii) local iliIili1lIiIIIl1ilI = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[25269] local lIlIlI1iiiliIIiil1i1l = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[127128] local lIll1iiiIiIIliIIl1liI = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[43240] local l111I1iI1I1lilIIli1 = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[23653] local II11iiI1iI1i1lI1i1l = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[43240] - ill1liill1illiliill if lIlIlI1iiiliIIiil1i1l > 255 then lIlIlI1iiiliIIiil1i1l = i11lliiiilIliiiIl11[lIlIlI1iiiliIIiil1i1l - 256][IiIIillI1ll1IllIiIl] else lIlIlI1iiiliIIiil1i1l = IlliIiilIli11liIlIl[lIlIlI1iiiliIIiil1i1l] end if iliIili1lIiIIIl1ilI > 255 then iliIili1lIiIIIl1ilI = i11lliiiilIliiiIl11[iliIili1lIiIIIl1ilI - 256][IiIIillI1ll1IllIiIl] else iliIili1lIiIIIl1ilI = IlliIiilIli11liIlIl[iliIili1lIiIIIl1ilI] end if lIlIlI1iiiliIIiil1i1l == iliIili1lIiIIIl1ilI ~= (l111I1iI1I1lilIIli1 ~= 0) then I11I11llIIiI1lI1i1I = I11I11llIIiI1lI1i1I + 1 end end I111li1IIII1llIiiIl[12] = function(l11i111lI1ilIlilil1, lIli1iIllI1I1IlIIllll) local lIlIlI1iiiliIIiil1i1l = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[127128] local l111I1iI1I1lilIIli1 = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[23653] local iliIili1lIiIIIl1ilI = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[25269] local lIll1iiiIiIIliIIl1liI = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[43240] local II11iiI1iI1i1lI1i1l = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[43240] - ill1liill1illiliill if lIlIlI1iiiliIIiil1i1l == 1 then return true end local IliIiil1i1IIilll1l1 = l111I1iI1I1lilIIli1 + lIlIlI1iiiliIIiil1i1l - 2 if lIlIlI1iiiliIIiil1i1l == 0 then IliIiil1i1IIilll1l1 = l1lIliii11iIi1I1l11 end return true, l111I1iI1I1lilIIli1, IliIiil1i1IIilll1l1 end I111li1IIII1llIiiIl[9] = function(l11i111lI1ilIlilil1, lIli1iIllI1I1IlIIllll) local iliIili1lIiIIIl1ilI = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[25269] local II11iiI1iI1i1lI1i1l = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[43240] - ill1liill1illiliill local lIlIlI1iiiliIIiil1i1l = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[127128] local lIll1iiiIiIIliIIl1liI = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[43240] local l111I1iI1I1lilIIli1 = l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[23653] for iiI1llli1I1IiiIlIIl = l111I1iI1I1lilIIli1, lIlIlI1iiiliIIiil1i1l do IlliIiilIli11liIlIl[iiI1llli1I1IiiIlIIl] = nil end end lIlI1iiIIill1lillIIli = { I111li1IIII1llIiiIl[6], I111li1IIII1llIiiIl[7], I111li1IIII1llIiiIl[14], I111li1IIII1llIiiIl[2], I111li1IIII1llIiiIl[5], I111li1IIII1llIiiIl[9], I111li1IIII1llIiiIl[1], I111li1IIII1llIiiIl[12], I111li1IIII1llIiiIl[3], I111li1IIII1llIiiIl[4], I111li1IIII1llIiiIl[10], I111li1IIII1llIiiIl[16], I111li1IIII1llIiiIl[8], I111li1IIII1llIiiIl[0], I111li1IIII1llIiiIl[15], I111li1IIII1llIiiIl[13], I111li1IIII1llIiiIl[11] } local function II11IIiiiliili1llll() while true do local l11i111lI1ilIlilil1 = lIliliiIi1lIIIIl1111i[I11I11llIIiI1lI1i1I] I11I11llIIiI1lI1i1I = I11I11llIIiI1lI1i1I + 1 local lIi1i1llIIIliiIIil1, lIl11Il1llIi1i1llilll, i1I1Iill1Il11liIill = lIlI1iiIIill1lillIIli[l11i111lI1ilIlilil1[77834] + 1](l11i111lI1ilIlilil1) if lIi1i1llIIIliiIIil1 then return lIl11Il1llIi1i1llilll, i1I1Iill1Il11liIill end end end local lIlIIliIIilIIlIliIIiI, lIl11Il1llIi1i1llilll, i1I1Iill1Il11liIill = llliilI1II1lillI111(II11IIiiiliili1llll) if lIlIIliIIilIIlIliIIiI then if lIl11Il1llIi1i1llilll then return I1liI1i1Il11lIi11l1(IlliIiilIli11liIlIl, lIl11Il1llIi1i1llilll, i1I1Iill1Il11liIill) end else local iiilll1Ii1lI1ll1iiI = lIlI111l1iIllIII1Iiil("Luraph Script:" .. (i1l11I1lI11l11ilIi1[I11I11llIIiI1lI1i1I - 1] or "") .. ": " .. lIlIlI1iI1illIiIll1i1(lIl11Il1llIi1i1llilll), "[^:]+:%d*: ", function(l1IIlIIlii1lillIii1) if not l1lIl1lll11l11l1IlI(l1IIlIIlii1lillIii1, "Luraph Script:%d") then return "" end end) lII1Iil11llII1II1Ii(iiilll1Ii1lI1ll1iiI, 0) end end lIliiIiiIIIIIi111Illi(lIlIIIiIIi1lIiIlII111, lIl1lI1li1IIIl1111Ill) return lIlIIIiIIi1lIiIlII111 end local Il1i11lI1iiI1lli1Il = lIlIlI1Ii1li1lI1lIIli() return lIliIiIl1ili1IillIiIl(Il1i11lI1iiI1lli1Il, lIl1lI1li1IIIl1111Ill)() end IIi1IIlI1IIIii1i1II("LPH|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lilIi1I1iliiiI1I1Il()) 
return 'hacker'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's obfuscated with Luraph, an obfuscator almost always used to hide malware. Running [LuraphDeobfuscator](https://github.com/josephcsible/LuraphDeobfuscator) (my fork of a fork, since [the original](https://github.com/TheGreatSageEqualToHeaven/LuraphDeobfuscator) disappeared - I had no part in its creation) and then [unluac](https://github.com/HansWessels/unluac) reveals that it's really the following:

```
local L0_0
L0_0 = {}
if require == print then
  print("4921139774")
else
  require(4922896222)
end
```

In particular, the hint is intentionally trying to mislead you. It wants you to do `require = print` to see what it's trying to require without deobfuscating it, but if you do that without also doing `print = nil` or something like it, then it will detect it and print the wrong answer.

Comment: Indeed, `require = print` isn't a good idea for this kind of thing; better do `require = function(...) print(...) end` as it creates a new, unique function. Better yet, make use of `debug.sethook` ;)